# How to get selected Radio button value on another JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc

Here in my application I am creating page with set of Questions. This Questions are coming from database. Now I want to insert user selected answer for each question in to database for that I will need the value of user selected answer. I wrote below code in my viewQuestionList.jsp page.

```
<form method='post' action='/OnlineExam/SubmitExam'>

    <div>
        <h1>Question Paper</h1>

        <c:choose>
            <c:when test='${QuestionList == null || empty QuestionList}'>
         No Questions available at this time
    </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>

                <c:forEach items="${QuestionList}" var="curQuestion">
                    <p>${curQuestion.getQuestion()}</p>
                    <input type="radio" value="a" name="${curQuestion.getQuestionId()}">${curQuestion.getOption1()}<br>
                    <input type="radio" value="b" name="${curQuestion.getQuestionId()}">${curQuestion.getOption2()}<br>
                    <input type="radio" value="c" name="${curQuestion.getQuestionId()}">${curQuestion.getOption3()}<br>
                    <input type="radio" value="d" name="${curQuestion.getQuestionId()}">${curQuestion.getOption4()}<br>

                </c:forEach>

                <button type="SUBMIT" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit">SUBMIT</button>

            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: so what is the problem?you can simply do `request.getParameter("questionId");`

Comment: Actually there are 10 questions on page. so there will be 10 question id. I can get only last question id by doing request.getParameter("questionId"); So my question is How to retrieve id of group of radio button on servlet ?

Comment: Hi @singhakash thanks for the reply. To more clarify: QuestionList has multiple questions. so every time in loop it creates new radio button which has different question Id.  and I want to get selected answer of each question Id. thts where I am stuck.! hope you get my question.

Comment: if the question ids are unique then you will surely get all the values just get all the question ids from db im servlet and iterate over it do `getParameter` for each id